# Not getting any sound What is my solution?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, video.js

Hello you fellow stackflowers! How are you doing today? Hey I got a question, when I play a video, I'm not getting any sound! How could I fix that? I'm using video js.
This is my code:

```
<script>
var video = videojs("#VideoPlayer",{
  autoplay:'true',
  controls: 'true',
 loop: 'true',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Autoplay in any browser requires the video to be muted.  Typically, that is done by adding the muted attribute.  Perhaps video.js does this for you, since you asked for autoplay to be on.

Doug